# Using groupby and cumsum to get a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

| Class | Received | Issued |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FD | 10 | 0 |
| FD | 0 | 2 |
| RM | 5 | 0 |
| RM | 0 | 3 |
| FD | 0 | 2 |
| PM | 5 | 0 |
| PM | 1 | 0 |
| RM | 1 | 0 |
| FD | 4 | 0 |

I require the dataframe below:

| Class | Received | Issued | Remaining Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FD | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| FD | 0 | 2 | 8 |
| RM | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| RM | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| FD | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| PM | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| PM | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| RM | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| FD | 4 | 0 | 10 |

The remaining quantity column is cumsum() of received - issued per class. I have tried different methods but I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```py
df["Remaining Quatity"] = (g := df.groupby("Class").cumsum())["Received"] - g["Issued"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Class  Received  Issued  Remaining Quatity
0    FD        10       0                 10
1    FD         0       2                  8
2    RM         5       0                  5
3    RM         0       3                  2
4    FD         0       2                  6
5    PM         5       0                  5
6    PM         1       0                  6
7    RM         1       0                  3
8    FD         4       0                 10
```

---

OR: Using `.pipe`:

```py
df["Remaining Quatity"] = df.groupby("Class").cumsum().pipe(lambda g: g["Received"] - g["Issued"])
```

---

OR: Using `.eval`:

```py
df["Remaining Quatity"] = df.groupby("Class").cumsum().eval("Received - Issued")
```

Comment: very nice use of the walrus operator :)

Comment: Why use the walrus instead of just `g = df.groupby("Class").cumsum()` then `g["Received"] - g["Issued"]`? Either way, I prefer the other options because they don't leave a temp variable lying around.

Comment: @wjandrea I just wanted to do it in one line. But yes, I prefer the `.eval` version, it looks clean.

Answer (score 4):

```
df['Remaining Quantity'] = df.groupby('Class').apply(
    lambda x: x['Received'].cumsum() - x['Issued'].cumsum()
    ).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  Class  Received  Issued  Remaining Quantity
0    FD        10       0                  10
1    FD         0       2                   8
2    RM         5       0                   5
3    RM         0       3                   2
4    FD         0       2                   6
5    PM         5       0                   5
6    PM         1       0                   6
7    RM         1       0                   3
8    FD         4       0                  10
```

Comment: I got the same thing, but with `.droplevel(0)` instead of `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`. Do you know if there's any difference?

Comment: I think they should be equivalent @wjandrea

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution :

```
df["Remaining Quatity"] = (
    df.eval("tmp=Received-Issued").groupby("Class")["tmp"].cumsum()
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  Class  Received  Issued  Remaining Quatity
0    FD        10       0                 10
1    FD         0       2                  8
2    RM         5       0                  5
3    RM         0       3                  2
4    FD         0       2                  6
5    PM         5       0                  5
6    PM         1       0                  6
7    RM         1       0                  3
8    FD         4       0                 10
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `.stack` to compute the difference and then assigning the value back along the index.

```
df['Remaining Quality'] = df.assign(
            Issued=df['Issued'] * -1).set_index('Class',append=True)\
           .stack().groupby(level=1).cumsum().unstack(-1).droplevel(1,0)['Issued']

print(df)

  Class  Received  Issued  Remaining Quality
0    FD        10       0                 10
1    FD         0       2                  8
2    RM         5       0                  5
3    RM         0       3                  2
4    FD         0       2                  6
5    PM         5       0                  5
6    PM         1       0                  6
7    RM         1       0                  3
8    FD         4       0                 10
```